# update multiple list items using Sharepoint Plus and ids

Tags: javascript, sharepointplus

I'm using Sharepoint Plus and want to update multiple list items based on ids.

I have one input text to update only title field and an array of IDs from selected my list items as a function, (to simplify , i have made the list of the ids as the following):

```
...
<input id="Title" name="Title" type="text">
<script>
var fileds = {};
 $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   fileds['Title']= $("#Title").val();
   $SP().list("MyName").update({Title: [fileds] },{
     where:"ID in (34, 45, 55, 33)"
  });
 });    
</script>
```

if i'm using only one id --> *where:"ID = 34"* then it is working but i want to update multiple records with the same value from text filed. is there and possibility to do that ?  any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing it right.

It should be:

```html
<script>
 $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var title = $("#Title").val();
   $SP().list("MyName").update({Title:title},{
     where:"ID in ['34', '45', '55', '33']"
  });
 });
</script>
```

It means that for items with ID #34, #45, #55 and #33, the column 'Title' will be updated with the value `title`.

You had several issues:

1. The WHERE clause with `IN` should have the parameters between `[]` and not `()`, and I think the `""` are also required (https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/lists.html#parse)
2. The [`update` function](https://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/lists.html#update) must have an one-to-one value, so if you define a field name, it should only have one value

Another possibility is to do pass an array to `update()`:

```html
<script>
 $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var title = $("#Title").val();
   var arrID = [34, 45, 55, 33];
   var toUpdate = [];
   arrID.forEach(function(id) {
     toUpdate.push({ID:id, Title:title})
   })
   $SP().list("MyName").update(toUpdate);
 });
</script>
```